# NSColor Core Foundation counterpart?

Tags: cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Is there a “toll-free bridged” Core Foundation counterpart for NSColor?

`CGColorRef` doesn't seem to like `NSColor` and vice versa?

Basically we'd like to create NSColor (or compatible) objects from our C++ wrapper/framework classes that store the actual r/g/b/a values. I know we could use Objective-C++ but staying in the C++ world would be preferrable!

Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert a `CGColorRef` to an `NSColor` like this:

```
CGColorRef cgColor = ...;
NSColorSpace *colorSpace = [[[NSColorSpace alloc] initWithCGColorSpace:CGColorGetColorSpace(cgColor)] autorelease];
NSColor *nsColor = [NSColor colorWithColorSpace:colorSpace 
                                     components:CGColorGetComponents(cgColor) 
                                          count:CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cgColor)];
```

If you use this a lot, it's probably best to put this in an `NSColor` category method.

If your colors are all in the RGBA colorspace, it might be easier to just use a simple `struct` in your C++ code and use `colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:` for conversion.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I guess we'll go with a NSColor category that initializes a new NSColor object straight from our wrapper class!